# Emacs mode multiline comments

Tags: emacs, elisp

What's the correct method for defining multi-line comments in an emacs mode 
(like C's /* */)?  The elisp examples I see are for comments that start with a single delimiter and end at the end of the line (like C++'s // or perl's #).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's like this:

```
(define-derived-mode my-mode
    awk-mode "my"
    "My mode"
  (setq comment-multi-line nil) ; maybe
  (setq comment-start "/* ")
  (setq comment-end "*/"))
```

But there are subtleties; maybe you want

```
/*  line one   */
/*  line two   */
/*  line three */
```

or maybe you want

```
/*  
    line one
    line two
    line three
*/
```

This is affected by your `comment-style`, which you can customize (`M-x customize-variable comment-style`). For something like the first example choose `indent`, for the second example, `extra-line`.

It's all defined in `newcomment.el`, which you can read about if you `M-x describe-variable comment-start`.

Answer (score 3):

Tom's answer covers creating comments; if you want your mode to be aware of comments, you need to fixup the syntax table.

Relevant reading:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Syntax-Tables.html#Syntax-Tables

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent guide for adding comment goo to an emacs mode.
[Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_comment_handling.html)